# Testing javascript function within angular scope using jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have created an application in angularjs, i have learned writing jasmine unit test cases for angularjs, but the problem is that in my application i am having both angular scope methods as well as normal JavaScript functions, when i wrote test case for that function i am getting the following exceptions

```
ReferenceError: isInvalid is not defined
    at null.<anonymous> (http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/:83:16)
    at jasmine.Block.execute (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:1064:17)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at jasmine.Queue.start (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2049:8)
    at jasmine.Spec.execute (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2376:14)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2096:31)
    at onComplete (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2092:18)
    at jasmine.Spec.finish (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2350:5)
    at null.onComplete (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2377:10)
    at jasmine.Queue.next_ (http://jasmine.github.io/1.3/lib/jasmine.js:2106:14)
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3oyg5Lt8/)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).controller("Controller", function($scope) {
    $scope.addNumbers = function(val1, val2) {
        var result = isInvalid(val1) + isInvalid(val2),
            tax = 6,
            watt = 5;
        return (result + tax + watt);
   };   
});

function isInvalid(value) {
   if( value=== null || value === undefined || value === '' ||isNaN(parseInt(value)))
   {
       return 0;
   }
   else
   {
       return value;
   }
}

describe('Testing a controller', function() {
    beforeEach(module("myApp"));
    var ctrl, scope;
    beforeEach(inject(function($controller, $rootScope) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        ctrl = $controller("Controller", {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    it('test add numbers', function() {
        expect(scope.addNumbers(2,6)).toMatch(19);
    });

    it('test isInvalid', function() {
        expect(isInvalid(6)).toMatch(6);
    });
});

(function() {
    var jasmineEnv = jasmine.getEnv();
    jasmineEnv.updateInterval = 1000;

    var trivialReporter = new jasmine.TrivialReporter();
    jasmineEnv.addReporter(trivialReporter);

    jasmineEnv.specFilter = function(spec) {
        return trivialReporter.specFilter(spec);
    };

    $(function() {
        jasmineEnv.execute();
    });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

`isInvalid` is defined inside the scope of the Controller function. To test it you should, either define the function outside the controller's scope (public) or register it in the `$scope` object. Basically, jasmine can't look inside the controller.

Comment: how to define the function outside the controller's scope (public)